# HTML form body empty with NodeJs

Tags: html, node.js, forms, file-upload, body-parser

I apologize if this question seems really familiar. I have multiple places where I am using forms to send data to server. Here is the html.

```html
 <form action="/dashboard/inventory/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="receivingdate" placeholder="Select Receiving Date" required />
     <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="workorderfile" required />
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
         Submit
     </button>
 </form>
```

In my `app.js` I have

```js
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Yet When I try to access the date with `req.body` I get an empty object and `null` for `req.files`
I have used this process on multiple places yet this is the only form that is giving me a headache.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a name attribute to input tags.

Answer (score 1):

here is simple code

```
<form  action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label>write name</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" value="">
  <br></br>
  <label>Upload image</label>
  <input type="file" name="photo"  />
  <br></br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

router file

```
router.post('/upload',  (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.files.file;
  const img = req.files.photo;
```

in my main app.js file

```
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
 const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(fileUpload());
```

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to attach a name attribute. I am so sorry. THANKS.